# Add progress Dialog showing loading page on webview in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, webview

I am new to iOS development.Is there any method to show a progress dialog on webview which show loading page while page is being loading and dismisses after the page loaded.

Please recommend some good tutorials

*Thanks in advance*

here is my code what i am doing but nothing shows

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIActivityIndicatorView*loadingIndicator;
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize myWebview;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
self.myWebview.delegate = (id<UIWebViewDelegate>)[self class];
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];          
activityIndicator.center = self.myWebview.center;
[activityIndicator setHidden:YES];
self.loadingIndicator=activityIndicator;
[self.view addSubview:self.loadingIndicator];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://getaservice.pk/joomla"];
self.myWebview.delegate = (id<UIWebViewDelegate>)[self class];
NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[myWebview loadRequest:request];
[super viewDidLoad];


}
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

     -(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request     navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
[self.loadingIndicator startAnimating] ;
[self.loadingIndicator setHidden:NO];
return YES;
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
[self.loadingIndicator setHidden:YES];
[self.loadingIndicator stopAnimating] ;
}

-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
[self.loadingIndicator setHidden:YES];
[self.loadingIndicator stopAnimating] ;
 }

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }

 - (IBAction)button:(id)sender {

}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@interface
// declare a loading indicator
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIActivityIndicatorView*loadingIndicator;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
        self.webview.delegate = (id<UIWebViewDelegate>)[self class];
        UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
        activityIndicator.center = self.webview.center;
        [activityIndicator setHidden:YES];
        self.loadingIndicator=activityIndicator;
        [self.view addSubview:self.loadingIndicator];
        [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [self.loadingIndicator startAnimating] ;
    [self.loadingIndicator setHidden:NO];
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [self.loadingIndicator setHidden:YES];
    [self.loadingIndicator stopAnimating] ;
}

-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
     [self.loadingIndicator setHidden:YES];
     [self.loadingIndicator stopAnimating] ;
}
```

I Think you are searching for this, else am sorry..

Comment: use of undeclare identifier 'ActivityIndicator'

Comment: i have loaded the page but still nothing shown on loading

Comment: modify the color by replacing this code        UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

Comment: I think you are very new to iOS. Try adding your indicator above the webview in your storyboard, view controller. Set Required color.

Comment: please see my above code thats what i am doing but shows no dialog

Comment: I got shown the indicator but now the problem is that does not disapear on page loaded

Comment: Use - (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView , to show indicator. See my edited code.

Comment: every thing is good but  webviewdidfinishload is not working now

Answer (score 1):

Take a Activity Indicator in your view and place it in center of screen or webview.Default hide activity indicator.

Now, When you load webPage then show activity indicator until your webpage completely load.

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView1{
if (webView1.isLoading){
    return;
}
[self.activityView stopAnimating];
self.activityView.hidden = TRUE;
```

}

Comment: have you add webView.delegate = self; in your code? or make webview selector to its delegate. You have to add <UIWebViewDelegate> in your .h file.